# Automatically signed APK via Gradle cannot be instaled since AS 3.0 (gradle 4.1)

Tags: android, gradle, apk, signing, android-studio-3.0

Since the update to Android Studio 3.0 with `gradle` 4.1 I'm facing this issue.

If I create apk using `Build` & Run, then take this apk (path app/build/outputs/apk/...) upload it to the device and try to install it (it's clean install app is not on device) I get "App not installed" error.

My `gradle` settings snippet:

```
signingConfigs {

        release {
            storeFile file("../path_to_keystore/keystore.jks")
            storePassword "mypass"
            keyAlias "myAlias"
            keyPassword "mypass"
        }
    }

buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            versionNameSuffix "-debug"
        }
    }
```

If I sign APK via Generate Signed APK wizard, apk is installed. Build and Run approach worked in previous Android Studio versions.

Anybody facing the same issue? And know how to fix automatic sign via Gradle?

Some additional info:

- the instant run is disabled
- build via Build & Run worked with debug and release configurations
- build and run version uploads and install correctly on device via AS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into this yesterday. The output of Run no longer can be directly installed via means other than Android Studio, apparently. Android Studio automatically adds [`android:testOnly="true"` to the `<application>` element in the manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#testOnly). Despite the documentation, this APK cannot be installed by any means other than Android Studio — I was specifically trying to install via `adb` and failed.

Running the `assembleRelease` task gives you an APK that you can use, as does the in-Studio wizard.